# C# add to queue in parallel and listen for queue propagation

Tags: c#, .net, queue, task-parallel-library, producer-consumer

I am new to multithreaded programming. I have a program that needs to query a database and then perform some data manipulation on the data returned. Due to the structure of my org I have to make an individual call to the database to retrieve a single user's account info. My task involves collecting data over thousands of accounts.

Currently, I am using Parallel.ForEach() to query the database and adding all elements into a ConcurrentList. Once all data has been returned from the database I then perform my manipulation in a synchronous fashion.

Besides any glaring issues the one thing I don't like is keeping a large list in memory and essentially being blocked until the lengthy database process is finished. I would like to be able to push the data into a queue and then begin processing the data as soon as data is added. The consuming process does not need to be parallel or async. I just need it to be able to listen for when something is added to the queue or that the queue is not empty.

**Parallel Process:**

```
public static ConcurrentBag<CombinedAccountInfo> GetAllAccountInfo(List<AccountInfo> accountList, string dbConnName)
    {
        logger.Info("Fetching Data");
        var concurrentCombinedData = new ConcurrentBag<CombinedAccountInfo>();
        Parallel.ForEach(accountList, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 5 }, r =>
        {
            try
            {
                var userPrefs = new List<UserPreference>().queryData(Queries.UserPrefQuery, dbConnName);

                concurrentCombinedData.Add(new CombinedAccountInfo()
                {
                    AccountName = r.AccountName,
                    AccountId = r.AccountId,
                    LastLoginDate = r.LastLoginDate,
                    AccountHandle = r.AccountHandle,
                    UserPreferences = userPrefs 
                });
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                logger.Error(e);
            }
        });

        return concurrentCombinedTransaction;
    }
```

I have done some reading on Dataflow and saw a few articles about Reactive Extensions. However I can seem to find any simpler examples of multiple producers feeding into a single consumer. Any suggestions or ideas how to better reach the end goal would be greatly appreciated.

**SOLVED**

I'll be using the answer that [Scott Hannen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5101046/scott-hannen) provided. Because the manipulation is small and not very intensive each process can handle it rather than trying to tie everything back into a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you want is to operate on each account as you retrieve it from the database then you could do exactly that instead of adding elements to a `ConcurrentBag<CombinedAccountInfo>`.

```
public static ConcurrentBag<CombinedAccountInfo> GetAllAccountInfo(
    List<AccountInfo> accountList, 
    string dbConnName,
    Action<CombinedAccountInfo> doSomethingWithTheAccountInfo)
```

Then, as you get each element from the database,

```
doSomethingWithTheAccountInfo(accountInfo);
```

Comment: If the operations on the data are short then it probably doesn't make any difference. The alternative would be putting items in a ConcurrentQueue and having a separate process read from that queue, but then it will be polling for items in the queue. Unless you're seeing performance issues I wouldn't worry about doing anything complex to make it faster.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with using Actions and Funcs. Are you suggesting I create an action that points to the method that processes the data? I like that idea, it seems to answer my question. This is more hypothetical but could become a use case, what if I wanted to return a value when a parallel process has completed? For example, if there was a specific user preference I wanted back from each account, could I have the parallel task return something? Would that require using a Func?

Comment: Yes. The only difference between an Action and Func is that an Action represents a method with no return value while a Func returns something. Sometimes I use a delegate, which is like declaring a method signature and giving it a name. The reason I like that is because it makes it explicit what the method I'm passing in is for. But I keep going back and forth on that.

Answer (score 0):

Although I really believe that you should query all user preferences at once, as that will improve the performance on your database (really *BIG TIME*), if you want to something like this:

```
public void Answer<T>(List<Guid> ids)
{
    var stack = new ConcurrentStack<T>();

    Parallel.ForEach(ids, (id) =>
    {
        T value = GetData<T>(id);

        stack.Push(value);
    });

    Parallel.For(0, ids.Count, (i) =>
    {
        T item;
        while (!stack.TryPop(out item))
        {
            // sleep
        }
        Process(item);
    });
}
```

But did I already mention, I think you should not go there?

Comment: If I had the ability I would query all preferences at once however all the data is behind SOA and I have to make webservice calls to retrieve it. I can only make SOA calls per account, theres no batch or list of accounts I can have it go through. Thank you for the suggestion I'll see if there are maybe better solutions before trying this.